# GlusterFS on CentOS 8 - Replicated Volume Creation Failed

Tags: centos, glusterfs

I start learning GlusterFS in a homelab that is consists of 4 CentOS 8 virtual machines. My lab setup is as in the following:

1. one VM act as Name Server (BIND) and Time Server (Chrony)
2. A cluster of 3 VMs where GlusterFS is installed, with dedicated
   XFS partition (`sdb1`) for Gluster in each. that partition is mounted
   to `/gfsPool/gBricks` directory.
3. `gfsvol01` directory created inside `/gfsPool/gBricks` on each node.

GlusterFS installation was smooth, as well as the clustering the 3 nodes.

when I came to create a replicated Gluster Volume, I faced an error as in the following:

```
gluster volume create gfsvol01 replica 3 transport tcp virthost01:/gfsPool/gBricks/gfsvol01 virthost02:/gfsPool/gBricks/gfsvol01 virthost03:/gfsPool/gBricks/gfsvol01

volume create: gfsvol01: failed: Multiple bricks of a replicate volume are present on the same server. This setup is not optimal. Bricks should be on different nodes to have best fault tolerant configuration. Use 'force' at the end of the command if you want to override this behavior.
```

When I used force, the following error occurred:

```
volume create: gfsvol01: failed: Commit failed on localhost. Please check the log file for more details.
```

Any idea how this can be fixed? I appreciate your help already.

P.S. I'm new to Linux in general, and it's my first time to deal with GlusterFS

Thanks,
Bahaddin